# how get feeds like facebook from sql database

Tags: php, android, sql-server

I am making an android app in which I am retrieving feeds from `SQL` data base using `PHP`.

I am fetching last 10 feeds from `SQL` database but when a user adds new feeds I start getting repeated feeds.

For example, my database table has 20 feeds at a particular moment and I have retrieved the 10 latest feeds. Now if someone adds new feeds, upon re-fetching I am getting the new ones plus the old ones.

How do I avoid these repeated feeds?

Comment: Store the ID. When you query the second time start the offset at the last known ID.

Comment: if you cant change the PHP end then just clear your old data and add the whole data again and set listview to scroll to the last know position

Comment: Thanx for your response, but @chris85 's solution won't work when the stored row gets deleted from the database.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the `publishTime` in your feed's database which will be publish time of feed and get the new feed from database after that particular last fetch time
which you can send in each request.

Answer (score 0):

may be you could order it according to latest feeds and limit to 10 in your query.

[Check out the query here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php)